# Did the father cheat on his wife in Happy End?

Tags: character, happy-end

In [Happy End (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5304464/), the daughter claims that her father "doesn't love his wife and doesn't love her too since she found out he is cheating on his wife" and the father seems to not "deny that definitely" and "admits that silently".

In the film, every detail seems to show that he is a good father that loves his daughter. And the daughter may just have illusions about him cheating on her mother since once she saw him talking to someone on the phone on the beach.

Was he actually cheating on his wife? What is the intention of the screen play?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the question to match the one in the title, since "Is he a good or bad father" is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: I was hesitated to change the title to good/bad to match the question, in that case it may get closed, lucky for me.

Comment: @F1Krazy You are right there is no good and bad, only truth. The truth is the father loves everyone at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia's plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_End_(2017_film)):

> After Eve's mother falls into a coma as a result of the poisoning, which everyone believes was a suicide attempt, **Eve is taken in by Thomas, her estranged father. She hacks into his computer and finds many e-mails and chat messages which show that he has a sadomasochistic sexual relationship with a female musician.**

[The screenplay](https://www.sonyclassics.com/awards-information/screenplays/happyend_screenplay.pdf) contains the text of some of these emails.

Comment: Wiki has a possible bug: the daughter doesn't hack into her father's computer, it shoudl be the scene of the mistress texting her father.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I saw this movie I thought the messaging on the Windows notebook is the daughter texting her friends about her new life in the new house. And there is a scene at around 0:40:25-0:40:40 of the user of the notebook whose face look like deformed and I thought it is the daughter's face under special lighting and covered partially by hair.

Now I found that the face is in fact the musician that later performened on her grandfather's birthday party (1:12:40). So she should be the woman.

But there is more problem, according to the screen play link above

> The Gambist (35) Thomas' mistress. Although invisible, merely evoked
>   or alluded to, the Gambist is, in this story, a bolt of eroticism.
>   Thomas is crazy about her body.

Why is she "invisible"? The possible answer is the film is not exactly the same with the screenplay.